# In an array, how do you group together objects based on one property that are being sorted by another, using .sort()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Using Javascripts .sort(), I have a list of objects that have a 'category' property and a 'subcategory' property. So far I have the list sorted by category using `item1.category().localeCompare(item2.category())` but within each category group I want to have the objects sorted by subcategory.

So far my array sorts into something like this:

```
[
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'}
]
```

Whereas I need it to be like this:

```
[
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'}
]
```

Also I can only use one sort() and can't do anything outside of it as it's being passed as a param to another function.

Comment: `a.category.localeCompare(b.category) || a.subcategory.localeCompare(b.subcategory)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an additional predicate to your sort function:

```
const arr = [ 
  { "field1": "a2", "field2": "b2" },  
  { "field1": "a1", "field2": "b2" },
  { "field1": "a1", "field2": "b1" }
];

arr.sort((a,b) => {
  return a.field1.localeCompare(b.field1) || a.field2.localeCompare(b.field2);
});
// [ {"field1":"a1","field2":"b1"},
//   {"field1":"a1","field2":"b2"},
//   {"field1":"a2","field2":"b2"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add another localeCompare on the subcategory, eg:

```
arr.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a.category.localeCompare(b.category)
        || a.subcategory.localeCompare(b.subcategory);
})
```

Comment: This treats category and subcategory equally. It should only compare subcategory when the categories are equal.

Comment: That is very true, replaced `+` with `||` XD

Answer (score 0):

Just expand your sorting function.

```
 categories.sort(function(a, b) {
   if(a.category < b.category){
     return -1;  
   }else if(a.category > b.category){
     return 1;
   }else{
     if(a.subcategory < b.subcategory){
       return -1
     }else if(a.subcategory > b.subcategory){
       return 1;
     }
   }
 });
```

Look at the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergey_Mell/htv6zs8g/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var values = [
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'}
];
console.log(values.sort(function (a, b) {
  var tmp_a = a.category + a.subcategory;
  var tmp_b = b.category + b.subcategory;

  if (tmp_a < tmp_b) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (tmp_a > tmp_b) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.category != b.category) {
        return (a.category > b.category) ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return (a.subcategory > b.subcategory) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

It checks to see if *category* is different. If it is different, then it sorts by that. Else (if *category* is the same), it sorts by *subcategory*.